# Android Support Library: getDrawable independent if vector or not

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable, android-support-design

When working with Android >= 5.0,

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)
```

Correctly parses the XML and returns a valid drawable. But when using the new [Vector Drawable Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) (Version 23.4, Gradle 2.1.2), this code **crashes under Android 4**.

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector

The solution would be to use

```
Drawable d = VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.icon, null);
```

But this crashes if the resource is not a vector resource:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Corrupt XML binary file

So what code has to be used instead of the first line so that it works with Android 4 and Android 6 and with vector and non-vector drawables - e.g. in all circumstances this line was used in an Android 5.0+ project? The support library article does not mention a way to perform this migration

Comment: I assume they were expecting developers to know up front whether the resource is a vector drawable or not. That's reasonable for app developers, less so for library developers. Off the cuff, I'd try the `VectorDrawableCompat`, and fall back to `getDrawable()` if you get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the following method to get drawable of Vector Drawable in pre 5.0.

```
Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(mContext, mImageTitleResId);
```

Comment: Available in support lib 24.2.x.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Helped us fix a always reproducing crash in our app while using vector drawables on pre 5.0 devices.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution.

You need to add the support VectorDrawable in your activity manually.

try this in your activity:

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

You should check this [blog entry](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.6qqljme8r) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. FYI, it is ``setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()`, the blog post has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

another possible solution what I found so far

```
ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.resources, resId, theme)
```

and context should be your activity (but not application context)